# Twitter bootstrap 2 - Modal - Can't update Div contents dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bunch of links with a class of `ShowDetails`. For each of these links I want to display a modal window, `MyModal`, and replace the content of a div, `DocDetails`. When I try to do this via the following JavaScript the div contents is never updated, but there is no error thrown:

```
$("a[class='ShowDetails']").on( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('#DocDetails').replaceWith( "details" );
    $('#MyModal').modal('show');
});
```

Any help resolving this would be great. My long term goal is to get content to repace `DocDetails` with from an AJAX response, this part works fine so isn't associated with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javascript looks correct to me so I would therefore assume that there is something wrong with the HTML.

I've knocked up a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dY6T/1/) incorporating your Javascript which works.

The jQuery `replaceWith` function removes the element with the specified ID and replaces it with the specified content, so in your example it would replace

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="DocDetails">One fine body…</div>
</div>
```

with

```
<div class="modal-body">
    model
</div>
```

Note that it has removed the div with the id DocDetails and replaced it with the text model not a div containing the text model. Therefore if you clicked a link again the div with the ID DocDetails would no longer exist. If you want the div to remain you could this instead:

```
$('#DocDetails').html( "details" );
```